# Access SQL to VBA to contain a loop

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have been trying to figure out how to use loops to solve a problem I am having with an access query. At present the query finds the first match and then stops looking so it returns an error. Is there a way in either SQL or VBA to loop it and then output the findings to a table. I attach the query for reference

```
SELECT [Data to create age of rail].Route, [Data to create age of rail].ELR, [Data to create age of rail].[Track ID], IIf([data to create age of rail].[yardage start]>=[track cat start mileage].[yardage start] And [yardage end]<=[data to create age of rail].[yardage start],[Track category],"error") AS Expr1
FROM [Data to create age of rail] 
INNER JOIN [Track Cat Start Mileage] 
ON ([Data to create age of rail].[Track ID] = [Track Cat Start Mileage].[Track Id]) 
AND ([Data to create age of rail].ELR = [Track Cat Start Mileage].ELR);
```

Answer (score 0):

The query in a better readable format using table aliases:

```sql
SELECT age.Route, age.ELR, age.[Track ID], 
    IIf(age.[yardage start]>=track.[yardage start] And [yardage end]<=age.[yardage start], 
        [Track category], "error") AS Expr1
FROM [Data to create age of rail] AS age 
INNER JOIN [Track Cat Start Mileage] AS track 
  ON (age.[Track ID] = track.[Track Id]) 
 AND (age.ELR = track.ELR);
```

You don't need a loop to get all records from a Select query, it always returns a set with all records that match the criteria.

What error are you getting? The "error" from the `IIf()` ?

Comment: Thanks for that I have never posted before, the issue is what I am trying to achieve is stop the select query finding the first match and stopping because there are other possible answers within the table. It is looking for a number between the two number. It is also linked on two fields so there could be more than one possible answer and i want the query to keep searching. please message me if that doesnt make sense

Comment: I'm sorry, it doesn't make much sense for me... Please edit your question and append sample data for both tables. Prepare them in Access or Excel and use http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html to create the text you can post. Make sure that the sample data reproduces your problem.